# Keeping track of each recursive call with an incrementer in Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog, increment

I am trying to increment a variable `M` by `1` with each recursive call.

I have been trying to work this out but am getting 'arguments not sufficiently instantiated' when querying.  I have a base case, and I increment using two variables reflexively in order to store the old value and unify the new value.

```
point(a,b).
point(a,c).
point(b,d).
point(c,d).
point(d,e).
point(f,g).

linkup(Point,Point,0).
linkup(Point1,Point2,Count) :-
   Counthelp is Count+1,
   point(Point1,Link),  
   linkup(Link,Point2,Counthelp).
```

Comment: You can't increment anything in Prolog. You can compute a value that is one greater than an existing variable though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
linkup(Point1,Point2,0) :- point(Point1,Point2).
linkup(Point1,Point2,Counthelp) :-
    point(Point1,Link),
    linkup(Link,Point2,Count),
    Counthelp is Count+1.
```

You do have to make sure you think "Prologishly". The `Counthelp` variable is an output so you have to pass it out and not pass it in. It also needs to be computed last so that `Count` is already unified.